# Performances of wrapping synchronous code in an async Task

Tags: c#, performance, asynchronous, wrapper

I've been writing a framework and, to keep it simple, let's say that I have a class that handle the communication with an hardware resource.
Let's also say that I've created an interface `IResource` that expose a Start method which is a `Task`, to handle the asynchronous case.
If a resource does not have an async method for starting (i.e. the .NET `SerialPort` as far as I know and I don't want to reinvent the wheel), is there any performance issues wrapping the sync code inside an
`await Task.Run(() => resource.StartSync())`?

Comment: There is always some overhead in using tasks. But if you are wrapping a serial port I would guess that efficiency is not super important. You still need to be careful to not introduce thread safety issues however.

Comment: For what purpose? Are you wanting to start that and allow the current thread to continue processing (so offloading `resource.StartSync` so the current executing thread does not have to wait for it to start)? Or are you trying to mimic async/await as it relates to suspending the thread so that I/O can complete without the main thread being locked and unavailable?

Comment: There is a little overhead (not a *lot*), but what there isn't is: a gain - unless you're actively trying to free up the current thread because it is "important", i.e. a UI thread or similar; is there a reason not to just call the method synchronously in this case? async-over-sync isn't an obvious win in most cases (and sync-over-async is a "nope, don't do that")

Comment: You may find this interesting: [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/)

Comment: Thanks all. The main reason is that in the interface I have declared the Start method as Task so, in order to implement it, all the concrete classes must have a public Task Start() method (which may be async). That's because most of the hardware I use support this (protocols like modbus, tcp, ecc...). I mean, I could always use Task.Run(..) whitout the await, that's for sure

Comment: .NET framework code itself in a similar situation just runs it synchronously (does not wrap into Task.Run), which is what I'd suggest. For example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnection.openasync?view=net-5.0

Comment: `The main reason is that in the interface I have declared the Start method as Task` ← Another option would be to simply do everything synchronously and return [`Task.CompletedTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask?view=net-5.0) at the end of the method to satisfy the interface signature.

Comment: This is rather opinion-based, but I recommend calling it synchronously but documenting that the interface method has known synchronous implementations. That way a GUI consumer will know to use `Task.Run` but a server consumer can call it normally via `await`.  [Some of my blogs on the subject](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html).

Comment: I suspected that there is some kind ov overhead in using tasks. It's not that importat at this stage because the start of all the hardware resources is made at startup and not during execution, so it douesn't bother me that much. I think that @Igor suggestion of using `Task.CompletedTask` is good because it does not change the way I waill start all of my resources